# Simple .htaccess rewrite to pass 1 parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Can someone please tell me what should my .htaccess file contain to create the following rewrite:

```
http://www.example.com/success
```

to call

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?q=success
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks,And how can I do this where "success" is a dynamic value?

Comment: Thanks again.. However when I try this I get a 403 Forbidden message - any idea why?

Comment: Wow - thanks for the fast reply :) Unfortunately - still 403 :(

Comment: Can't understand why! I tested and it works... Your `.htaccess` file has this rule only? If not, could you paste the file content, please?

Comment: I created a new .htaccess file with your code only and uploaded it to that folder. Once I uploaded it - all the requests for files return 403 forbidden... any idea what else could cause this?

Comment: I swear, I've no idea. Check `.htaccess` file permissions

Comment: Hi, This work only when I put the full path of the page (ie "http://mysite.com/index.php?q=") but it redirects to this page and doesn't keep the nice address in the address bar... Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

Following code I use for my site

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?q=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?q=$1
```

or you can write following

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?q=$1
```