# How to prevent 404 and use the URL as parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, parameters

I wanted to achieve url like this

> www.abcd.com/somename

We know that the folder does not exist on the server and will throw 404 immediately

But I'm looking forward if "`somename`" can be translated as

`www.abcd.com?q=somename` but still showing as www.abcd.com/somename
And "somename" will be passed to get method for a PHP DB Query like this

```
$name = $_GET['somename'];
```

Thank you

Comment: Use .htaccess and something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1231237/1400579)

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13760676/6140684) or search first! It would be a great idea to try first..

Comment: Thanks Antonis and DaveP
I will try both suggestion

Comment: Amazing both of you, i've tried both suggestion and both are working 
Thank you for investing your time
have a nice day :)

Comment: `FallbackResource /404.php` which could use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as an URL slug lookup on your database.