# Why is htaccess redirecting any requests to main page?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to use htaccess for rewrite URL to pass 1 parameter like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13760521/10325886) question. On this basis I tried to redirect.

My rewrite look like [this](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=d08958cd-fa78-53e9-8026-a3890be41e41);

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?pg=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately this is not works and it redirects all urls to the main page (even non-existent too).
Could you help me please what did I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "main page" here? It certainly will redirect everything to that `index.html` file, because that is what you explicitly coded.

Comment: @arkascha I mean the main page is the index.html. My goal would be to redirect by parameter (for example: `example.com/index.html?pg=home` to `example.com/home`). What should I change on the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your comment to the question it becomes clear what you are actually trying to do.

I assume this is what you are looking for, though I don't really understand what sense it makes to pass a HTTP GET aparameter to a html file...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([\w]+) /index.html?pg=$1 [END,QSA]
```

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess"), you definitely should prefer the first option if you have access to the configuration.

Apart from that the rewriting module has to be loaded and enabled in your http host and, in case you decide to use a dynamic configuration file, you need to take care that it is located in the http hosts's `DOCUMENT_TOOR` folder and is readable for the http server process.

Comment: Thanks! I have to use the AJAX and sql query in a single php file. This solved the problem.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that, but anyway: glad I could be of help!